# Импорт новостей с сайта в приложение

Tags: android, api, архитектура, html

Есть новостной сайт. Нужно написать приложение Андроид, в котором будут транслироваться новости с сайта... и будут обновляться по мере обновления на сайте. Как это лучше  реализовать? С помощью rss-ленты или нужно апи для сайта?

Comment: есть и ещё 1 вариант, парсить прям с сайта, но конечно лучше апи

Answer (score 3):

Можно чрез API, RSS или парсить загруженные HTML-ки.

В моём случае был проект похожий, там в RSS только последние 20-ть новостей отдавались, а c HTML - 30. Причём разный набор инфы был в обоих случаях, а API не было.

Решено было работой с обоими способами. Инфа с двух каналов складывалась в БД и уже оттуда выводилась на экран.

Для парсинга использовалась вот эта либа: [тык](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/).

Для БД эта - [тык](http://ormlite.com/).